# Is lightning case sensitive?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Is lightning case sensitive (or) is it something else that is causing this behavior? 
I was looking into Lightning badges on trailhead and when I tried to compile this code, as a salesforce developer I expected this code to compile ( not a good practice to have mix case).

```
<aura:component >
    <h1 style="font-size:16px"> Camping List </H1>
</aura:component>
```

But the component won't compile and gives the following error:

> Failed to save undefined: markup://prao6308:campingHeader:2,45:
>   ParseError at [row,col]:[3,45] Message: The element type "h1" must be
>   terminated by the matching end-tag "".

```
Can someone please throw some light on why the compiler wont match <h1> with </H1>?
```

Comment: As lightning is based on aura framework which is a type of JavaScript and JavaScript is case sensitive so I think lightning is also case sensitive

Comment: http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_lightning_case.htm  I remember using mix case and this has changed starting spring 15. @Tushar post your comment as answer I will accept :)

Comment: Also, XML is case-sensitive in the general sense (HTML is less particular), so this also makes sense.

Comment: Answer is added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As lightning is based on aura framework which is a type of JavaScript and JavaScript is case sensitive so lightning is also case sensitive.

And from [Spring 15 Release Notes](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_lightning_case.htm) it is mentioned that Lightning components are now case sensitive.