# lightning component:save button

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

hi Everyone can anyone help with my code. the problem is if im going to click save button of my lightning component the alertmessage Failed  will appear then it won't save my contact. hope you will help me.

here my lightning component

```
  <aura:component controller="CreateContactController">
    <aura:attribute name="newContact" type="Contact" default="{'sobjectType': 'Contact',
                                                              'FirstName':'',
                                                              'LastName':'',
                                                              'Email':'',
                                                              'Phone':''
                                                              }"/>
    <div class="slds-col slds-grid">
        <lightning:input aura:Id="ContactField" name="FirstName" type="text" value="{!v.newContact.FirstName}" Label="FirstName"/>
        <lightning:input aura:Id="ContactField" name="LastName" type="text" value="{!v.newContact.LastName}" Label="LastName"/>
        <lightning:input aura:Id="ContactField" name="Email" type="Email" value="{!v.newContact.Email}" Label="Email"/>
        <lightning:input aura:Id="ContactField" name="Phone" type="Phone" value="{!v.newContact.Phone}" Label="Phone"/>
        <lightning:button aura:Id="ContactField" label="save" onclick="{!c.savecontact}"/>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

And here's my Controller

```
({
    savecontact: function(component, event, helper) {
    var newcon = component.get("v.newContact");
    var action = component.get("c.save");
     action.setParams({ 
        "con": newcon
    });
     action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
           var state = a.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var name = a.getReturnValue();
               alert("success");
            }
         else if (state = "false")
         {
              alert("Failed");
         }
        });
    $A.enqueueAction(action)
}})
```

here my apex class:

```
public class CreateContactController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Contact save(contact con)
    {
     insert con;
        return con;
    }
}
```

Comment: `response.getState()` returns an ERROR  if the server-side fails to execute,there is no `false` state .

Comment: i cant save a record i can't find the error why it wont save the records on my org.

Comment: Are you getting any specific error in apex side.can you post that code too.

Comment: ive updated my post so you can see my apex class . but i think its not the problem.

Comment: AS @SFDC Learner said you have wrongly initialized the Field API Name

Comment: @zane - Can you update the aura:attribute from my answer?

Comment: i use you code below but i got an error -"Failed to save contactform.cmp: No COMPONENT named markup://dix found : [markup://c:contactform]: Source"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Lightning is case sensitive. Check this link : [Is lightning case sensitive?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/142288/is-lightning-case-sensitive)

By declaring it as "Email" in sObject and using "v.newContact.email" in input you actually create 2 email fields ("Email" and "email") you can see them if you debug the object on console.

```
<aura:component controller="CreateContactController">
<aura:attribute name="newContact" type="Contact" default="{sobjectType: 'Contact',
                                                           'FirstName':'',
                                                           'LastName':'',
                                                           'Email':'',
                                                           'Phone':''
                                                           }"/>
<form>
    <lightning:input aura:Id="ContactField" name="First Name" type="text" value="{!v.newContact.FirstName}" Label="First Name"/>
    <lightning:input aura:Id="ContactField" name="Last Name" type="text" value="{!v.newContact.LastName}" Label="Last Name"/>
    <lightning:input aura:Id="ContactField" name="Email" type="Email" value="{!v.newContact.Email}" Label="Email"/>
    <lightning:input aura:Id="ContactField" name="phone" type="Phone" value="{!v.newContact.Phone}" Label="Phone"/>
    <lightning:button aura:Id="ContactField" label="save" onclick="{!c.savecontact}"/>
</form>
```

2- Response state is ERROR not false.

```
({
savecontact: function(component, event, helper) {
    var newcon = component.get("v.newContact");
    var action = component.get("c.save");
    action.setParams({ 
        "con": newcon
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var name = response.getReturnValue();
            alert("success");
        }
        else if (state === "ERROR")
        {
            alert("Failed");
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Please correct your aura:attribute syntax to initialize the Contact Record.

```
<aura:attribute name="newContact" type="Contact" default="{'sobjectType': 'Contact',
                                                          'FirstName':'',
                                                          'LastName':'',
                                                          'Email':'',
                                                          'Phone':''
                                                          }"/>
```

Comment: its not working still dont save the record

Answer (score 0):

Do try this also

1. The API name of fields is case-sensitive. Email API name is *Email*
   not *email*
2. In controller code inside if statement use either  *==* or *===*(prefered).
3. See the Debug logs to encounter any other problem(if still exists).